# Should we make this answer Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki, specific-answer

[Is there an official Marvel Cinematic Universe viewing order?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45654/931)

- This answer is an ever-growing list which looks good for community wiki thing.
- Other users update the answer time to time (when new MCU property is released).
- The original answerer has earned lots of reputation already. Although, this shouldn't be a reason to make the answer community wiki, it points out that it shouldn't be considered a loss to OP besides he is cashing on mostly others' work now.

Should we convert the answer into community wiki?

Comment: Show us your research, have you *tried* to make it CW?

Comment: @Mooz Mods can do it.

Answer (score 8):

My gut instinct is to say no, for the simple reason that the OP didn't just post a list of the current films and then abandon it. Since it was posted, they've made [an additional 14 edits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/45654/timeline) with their original text and additional changes representing some **90% of the current text.**

As such, **their contribution to this answer represents a significant investment of their time and effort, for which they should be rewarded with any continuing rep.**

---

That's not to say that we shouldn't revisit this every couple of years, when the contribution of the community may have started to outweigh their contribution more heavily.

Answer (score 8):

### *We* should not do *anything*.

Per [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10101/70236) and the two answers, "no answer *should* be made CW". Sure, a user may choose to make an answer community wiki should they feel so, but **it's never an obligation**.

We could break this down by pros and cons:

**Pros**:

- *None*? If I understand this correctly, the only thing that will change is the amount of rep required to edit the post without the review queue: [from 2000 to 100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/348200). Do we need that? Who needs that? It's not like we desperately need drive-byers to add a valuable piece of information - well, we do, but it could be as easily done by anyone who has watched the films, which, judging by the number of [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) questions, is a lot.

**Cons**:

- Main contributor will lose rep

  - Here I disagree with your assertion that they're mostly getting rep for other users' work - it appears that the poster has been revisiting the answer regularly, and updating it, to the point when the majority of the post still belongs to them.
- We'll have less quality control - that's the downside of the lowered rep requirement. It's not really a bad thing (as one can catch that easily), but still.

Regardless of what *we* think, per this [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/), all parties should be consulted when *making* an answer a community wiki - meaning the final decision always rests with the answerer.